# Overloading ostream << on one class and output data of another class

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword, ostream

```
class Point2D
{
    protected:
            int x;
            int y;

    public:  
            Point2D () {x=0; y=0;}
            Point2D (int a, int b) {x=a; y=b;}        
            void setX (int);
            void setY (int);
            int getX ();
            int getY ();
};

class Line2D
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Line2D&);
    private:
            Point2D pt1;
            Point2D pt2;
            double length;                                  
    public: 
            Line2D () {pt1 = Point2D(); pt2 = Point2D();}
            Line2D (Point2D ptA, Point2D ptB) {pt1=ptA; pt2=ptB;}     

            void setPt1 (Point2D);
            void setPt2 (Point2D);
            Point2D getPt1 ();
            Point2D getPt2 ();                
};
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Line2D &l)
{
    //out << l.length << endl;    //Reading length works perfectly
    out << l.getPt1().getX() << endl;   //But how to read x from pt1 ?
    return out;
}
```

When I run these codes, I get **error** saying:

`no matching function for call to Line2D::getPt1() const` and

`note: candidates are: Point2D Line2D::getPt1() <near match>`.

If I am only trying to display `length` by overloading `<< operator` , it works perfectly. But when I try to print`x` and `y` of Class::Point2D, I get error.

**So what should be the proper way to print out `x` and `y` ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator (rightly) takes a `const` reference. So any methods called via that reference must be `const`. For example,

```
Point2D getPt1 () const;
                  ^^^^^
```

You should also make the `Point2D` class getters `const`.

Comment: Am I supposed to add the `const` on the `function declaration` or on the `function definition header` ? I am sorry if you find this question too basic..

Comment: +1 It's working. You are quick and precise in your reply. I hope I could +20 for you.. :)